# browser session expired = unable to complete event form

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I am using WP 5.4.2 - PHP 7.2 - CiviCRM 5.27.3 - the Plugin lite-speed 3.2.4 is activated.
UAT has raised this issue : "the browser session has expired you are unable to complete the event form subscription"

I see those post :
[All Contribution pages result in "Your browser session has expired" "Could not find a valid session key"](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/all-contribution-pages-result-in-your-browser-session-has-expired-could-not-f)
[Intermittent "Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission" errors](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/intermittent-your-browser-session-has-expired-and-we-are-unable-to-complete-you)

And I understand the root cause is  "cache management". Yes: if I delete cache on the host-admin  the form is now available to the end.

Someone said the solution is :

> Based on further investigation and discussion this seems to have been related to the WP Super Cache "Don’t cache pages with GET parameters. (?x=y at the end of a url)" setting being disabled.

But I don't understand if the fix is to be done :

- on WordPress = modify WP Super Cache
- on Lite-speed plugin = desactivate it
- on the Host = ?

BR Hervé

Comment: Can I ask for some more details? Are you using Cleaner URLs?   Does the event page look like `https://wpcv.test/civicrm/event/register/?id=1&reset=1` or `https://wpcv.test/civicrm?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=64`   The Starting page for the event signup is it a WP page using a shortcode?  Lastly, what is the URL it attempts to get to on the second page?   I agree caching is the issue and the above will help in suggestions on how to cause the pages not to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the WP Super Cache settings and it's all good...
(Deactivate visitors with cookies enabled)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer.
Yes I am using "WP Cleaner URL's":
-the starting page seen in civicrm-admin is: /event/info/?reset=1&id=2

page1= http://migrationccb.esy.es/2020/08/03/la-6eme-edition-des-vallees-breuilletoise-se-prepare/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&cid=0&reset=1&id=2

page2= http://migrationccb.esy.es/2020/08/03/la-6eme-edition-des-vallees-breuilletoise-se-prepare/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&_qf_Confirm_display=true&qfKey=4e151fc03d552da26b4ccef7fa052d83_8032

page3= http://migrationccb.esy.es/2020/08/03/la-6eme-edition-des-vallees-breuilletoise-se-prepare/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&_qf_ThankYou_display=true&qfKey=4e151fc03d552da26b4ccef7fa052d83_8032

The website is hosting by Hostinger that advice to activate LiteSpeed from his admin-page: it is LiteSpeed Cache 3.3 with defaut settings.
As a first step I decided now to

- un-activate "Mettre en cache les utilisateurs connectés"
- un-activate "Server stale"
- set "shedule purge time" at 00:01

Thank you for suggestions