# Error type: Could not find a valid session key

Tags: wordpress

> We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be
>   enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable
>   cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error
>   persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.
> Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are
>   accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured
>   Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are
>   accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like
>   http://myotherexample.org.
> Error type: Could not find a
>   valid session key.

### BELOW IS THE CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR THE ERROR "Error type: Could not find a valid session key"

```
$update_email = civicrm_api3('Email','get', $update_email_params);
            if (isset($update_email['id']) && $update_email['values'][0]['email'] !=$objectRef[$parameters['email']]){
                $update_email_final = civicrm_api3('Email','create', [
                  'sequential'=> 1,
                  'contact_id'=> $custom_44_result['id'],
                  'email'     => $objectRef[$parameters['email']],
                  'is_primary'=> 1,
                  'id' => $update_email['id'],
                ]); 

            }
```

Above is the update email code snippet which 
--- when placed gives error Could not find a valid session key 
--- when removed the error vanishes and process is completed

The complete code is as seen below

```
define('FirstName2','custom_47');
define('LastName2','custom_48');
define('Email2','custom_50');
define('CID2','custom_49')
add_filter( 'civicrm_post', 'alter_profiles_event', 10, 4  );
function alter_profiles_event($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef){
  if (is_user_logged_in()){
    if ($objectName == 'Profile'  && ($op == 'edit' ||$op == 'create' ) && isset($objectRef[FirstName1])) {
      $parameters = array(
        'first_name' => FirstName2,
        'last_name' =>LastName2,
        'email' =>Email2,
        'cid' => CID2,
      ); 
      civicrm_alter_family_members($objectRef,$parameters);
    }
  }
}

function civicrm_alter_family_members($objectRef,$parameters) {
   $custom_44_params = [
            'sequential' => 1,
            'contact_type' => "Individual",
            'first_name' => $objectRef[$parameters['first_name']],
            'last_name' => $objectRef[$parameters['last_name']],
          ];

          if (isset($objectRef[$parameters['cid']]) && !empty($objectRef[$parameters['cid']])) {
             $custom_44_params['contact_id'] = $objectRef[$parameters['cid']];
          }

          $custom_44_result = civicrm_api3('Contact','create',$custom_44_params);

          if (!empty($objectRef[$parameters['email']])){

            $update_email_params = [
              'sequential'=> 1,
              'contact_id'=> $custom_44_result['id'],
              'is_primary'=> 1,
            ];
            $update_email = civicrm_api3('Email','get', $update_email_params);
            if (isset($update_email['id']) && $update_email['values'][0]['email'] !=$objectRef[$parameters['email']]){
                $update_email_final = civicrm_api3('Email','create', [
                  'sequential'=> 1,
                  'contact_id'=> $custom_44_result['id'],
                  'email'     => $objectRef[$parameters['email']],
                  'is_primary'=> 1,
                  'id' => $update_email['id'],
                ]); 

            }

       }

}
```

I see updating civicrm email id gives session key error.
I also have

> CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync

plugin enabled.
Even when I disabled it, the error was existent.
So, ruled out above plugin to be causing the error.

When above CiviCRM email is updated, it updates the Email of the Wordpress User.

Comment: Your code seems to contain errors, e.g. `'first_name' => FirstName2,` so I'd fix those first and repost your code when you're sure your code is error-free.

Comment: Hi @ChristianWach, its not an error, Actually FirstName2 is a constant and similarly others.

Comment: Okay, I thought they might be but thought I'd check.

Comment: Have you tried executing the code after clearing the cache? The error seems to be from the session controller which is shown if a certain key is not found in the URL. If you're sure it errors from the above set of code, proceed by commenting a part of the above lines and check which part is causing the error.

Comment: Also see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2422/could-not-find-a-valid-session-key-unable-to-save-any-admin-forms?rq=1

Comment: Hi @jitendra-fuzion, I have checked it and he code snippet at the top is the code which gives the error ,so If i comment that it does not show the "error type: could not find a valid session key"

Comment: From what I see the whole code depends on the top section, i.e, `civicrm_alter_family_members()` won't be called until you keep the `alter_profiles_event()` function. Can you update the question with the section that is responsible for the error?

Comment: Hi @jitendra-fuzion, I have highlighted the code responsible for the error, let me know if you need further clarification?

Comment: @harshal I think what both of us are asking is for you to publish code that can be tested. What you have posted is a snippet of your code out of context - so much so that I assumed it had bugs. Can you rewrite the code so that others can test that it does indeed demonstrate the problem? We have no idea what your constants contain, for example. Remember: if someone can reproduce your problem, they can help.

Comment: Hi @ChristianWach I have added the constant values at top of code.